# How to run selenium on google cloud vm-instance,

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-compute-engine

I'm setting up a selenium script in google cloud vm-instance. I have tried running it using **Mozilla Firefox 60.4.0** and **geckodriver-v0.23.0**
Doing this i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

I then tried using **chromium 71.0.3578.80-1~deb9u1** and **chromedriver 2.45** but the error i get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5),platform=Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64)
```

How can i get selenium running. 
google-chrome is installed in **/usr/bin/google-chrome**
firefox is installed in **/usr/bin/firefox**

Comment: Im using debian for my operation and i have confirmed chrome is in the correct directory